# Packages for multiple allignment of Mass spec Data

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am searching for a good R package to align multiple spectra.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you're looking for, but have you looked at http://bioconductor.org ? The [PROcess](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/html/PROcess.html) package seems to have an align method. Also this site [here](http://www.ms-utils.org/wiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SoftwareList) has links to software and source code that may be relevant, even if not in R.